# Solving a nonhomogeneous transport equation $u_{t}+u_{x}+u_{y} = 5t^{2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solving the linear transport equation $u_{t}+u_{x}+u_{y}=5t^{2}$ with the initial value $u(x,y,0) = \cos(x)+\sin(y)$.

I am attempting to setup the method of characteristics to solve this problem, but I am unsure if I have the right idea. If there is a better method I am all ears, but here is what I am thinking for this particular PDE:

$$\frac{dx}{ds} = 1$$
$$\frac{dy}{ds} = 1$$
$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1$$

I am not at all confident about my selection here and any pointers would be appreciated. For example, how does the non-homogeneous situation come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_{t}+u_{x}+u_{y}=5t^{2}$$

You correctly wrote the next three equations which can be also presented on the Charpit-Lagrange form :
$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{ds} = 1 \\
\frac{dy}{ds} = 1 \\
\frac{dt}{ds} = 1
\end{matrix}
\quad\iff\qquad
\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{1} =\frac{dx}{1} = ds$$
But there was an equation missing for the complete system :
$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{1} =\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{du}{5t^2}$$
Solving them leads to the next characteristic equations :
$$x-t=c_1$$
$$y-t=c_2$$
$$u-\frac53 t^3=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $F(c_1\:,\:c_2\:,\:c_3)=0$ is :
$$F\left( (x-t)\:,\:(y-t)\:,\:(u-\frac53 t^3)\right)=0$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function of three variables.

Or equivalently on explicit form :
$$(u-\frac53 t^3)=f\bigg( (x-t)\:,\:(y-t)\bigg)$$
where $f$  is an arbitrary function of two variables.
$$\boxed{u(x,y,t)=\frac53 t^3+f\bigg( (x-t)\:,\:(y-t)\bigg)}$$

The arbitrary function has to be determined according to the specified condition $u(x,y,0)=\cos(x)+\sin(y)$ in order to find the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.
$$u(x,y,0)=\cos(x)+\sin(y)=\frac53 0^3+f\bigg( (x-0)\:,\:(y-0)\bigg)$$
$$f(x,y)=\cos(x)+\sin(y)$$
The function $f$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,t)=\frac53 t^3+\cos(x-t)+\sin(y-t)\:}$$

Comment: Thank you for writing this out. I thought about this after on my own and ended up with this exact solution, but I really did not have a good way for justifying what I did. This clears up basically all the questions I had!